# Could not load Ninject assembly in Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, ninject, nuget, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying to debug my application but at that time Error is shown as below:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have already added one of Assembly reference in Web.Config file as

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

then also the Debugging doesn't show the error.

Comment: What DLLs are in your bin directory when you look?

Comment: I have this problem in Azure, though everything works locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem get solved Because there was no need of Adding Ninject Package & there Libraries on My side of Application. 
I have just uninstalled all the packages of Ninject.

Sorry for wasting your time.